# etree get attribute as a value instead of a string

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

For a given Element, I want to check whether the `xsi:nil` attribute is set to true.

My current code is

```
xsinil = dataFact.get('{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil', False)
```

But instead of being `True` xsinil is of type string...

What's the best solution? I don't think this is very elegant:

```
xsinil=dataFact.get('{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}nil', False)
if xsinil == 'true' or xsinil == '1' :
    xsinil = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks nicer:

```
xsinil = dataFact.get('...', False) in ('true', '1')
```

It assigns `True` to `xsinil` variable only if result of `get` function is one of `True`, `'true'` or `'1'`.

Comment: -1 `Element.get(attribute_name, False)` will never return `True`

Comment: Agree, the final answer will be `xsinil = dataFact.get('......') in ('true', '1') `

Answer (score 1):

The second arg of `Element.get()` is almost irrelevant -- just don't use `True`.

All that you need is:

```
xsinil = dataFact.get('......') in ('true', '1')
```